# Calling Function with Ractive.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, ractivejs

I want to call start in JavaScript file. How can I do?

```
ractive.on('start', function(){
      ...
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

call [fire](http://docs.ractivejs.org/latest/ractive-fire) method.

```
ractive.fire('start');
```